# gii installation on Yii CMS

Tags: yii, content-management-system, gii

Can I add Gii( Yii extension) in Craft, which is a Yii CMS? If it can be added as extension, can you please give steps?

I have tried following given steps which were for Gii installation on Yii framework as below-

1) Extract the directories "giix-core" and "giix-components" from the
downloaded archive into your application's protected/extensions directory.

2) Configure the gii generator path in your application, like:

```
'modules' => array(
    'gii' => array(
        'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'generatorPaths' => array(
            'ext.giix-core', // giix generators
        ),
    ),
),
```

3) Configure your application to automatically load the giix component classes
when needed, like:

```
'import' => array(
    ...
    'ext.giix-components.*', // giix components
),
```

but it resulted in nothing( no error ),

http://dev.mysite.com/public/index.php?r=gii/

gave same index page as

http://dev.mysite.com/public/index.php.

What might me missing?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Craft strips out Gii components (along with lots of others that it has no need for) in their release, so you wouldn't be able to do this without some serious hacking of core Craft files.